# Creating an Xml string in C++

Tags: c++, xml

I have an array of strings.I want to make an xml string using the values of the array elements. I will pass this xml string  as a parameter to a .net webservice. Can anybody please tell me how do I make an xml string in c++? What library do I have to use and what are the methods?

The xml structure:

```
<xml>
<DeviceName></devicename>
<State></State>
<xml>
```

It wont have any attribute.Each array element will have devicename and state info. I dont want to write this into a file. i just want to create a string, which i can pass as a parameter to a webmethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use cmarkup, pretty simple to use.
http://www.firstobject.com/dn_markup.htm

Comment: How do i get the number of childnodes in a given node? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Erm, if you are just creating a string, why don't you simply do that? i.e.

```
std::ostringstream xml;

xml << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><some node><some child node/><some child node/></some node>";

xml.str(); // voila, here is your xml string...
```

No need to make it complicated..

If you REALLY do need a DOM, try TinyXML.

Comment: Because you just *know* someone's going to come along with a `&` or `<` and screw it all up.

Comment: @Ignacio, true, however, it still seems a little overkill for just replacing 5 entities (which you can do yourself!!) :)

Answer (score 1):

[libxml++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/)

Just keep using `xmlpp::Node::add_child()`.

Comment: There are so many version. Which one to download? Can you give me a link?